# functioning of (== ) in terms of hashCode

Tags: java, string, hashmap, key-value, bucket

String s1="abc";

String s2=new String("abc");

when we compare the both

s1==s2; it return false

and when we compare it 
with s1.hashCode()==s2.hashCode it return true

i know (==) checks reference id's .Does it returning true in above comparison because above hashCode are saved to same bucket??Please give me explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget that your hash codes are *primitive* integers, and comparing primitives using `==` will compare their *values*, not their references (since primitives don't have references)

Hence two strings having the same contents will yield the same hash code, and a comparison via `==` is perfectly valid.

The concept of a bucket is only valid when you put an object into a hashed collection (e.g. a `HashSet`). The value of the hash code dictates which bucket the object goes into. The hash codes themselves aren't stored.

Comment: thanxx  Agnew for the answer Can u please explain me why primitive integers dont have reference ids??

Comment: Simply because they're not objects. Not everything in Java is an object

Answer (score 1):

First comparison fails because they are two different objects.  Second comparison works because they are comparing the output of the hashCode() function, which produces the same value for both.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing objects using the equality operator (`==`) you are testing the equality of the Object Reference. Object References are only equal if they are the same object.

What is usually meant is the equality of the concept/information the object encapsulates. And this is best determined by the `equal(Object obj)` method.

For String this would be:

```
s1.equals(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the two Strings using `s1==s2`, you are comparing *references*. Since just before that line you created a new `String` object by copying the old one, both references refer to different objects, even though they contain the same value.

On the other hand, what the `hashCode` method does, depends on how it is implemented. The specification says that it has to comply with the `equals` function (whose behavior also depends on how it is implemented in the concrete type): If two objects are equal according to the `equals` method, they must return the same hash code. Since `equals` for `String` compares the values (not the references), both `hashCode` calls have to return the same value. And since `hashCode` returns an `int`, which is a primitive data type, your `==` comparison actually compares *values* and therefore works as expected.

Note: If you had done the same experiment for a class different from `String` that doesn't override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods (which is perfectly valid; it's just another way of defining equality on your type of object), it would have returned `false` for the `hashCode` comparison, too:

```
public class MyObject {

    private int value;

    public MyObject(MyObject toCopy) {
        this.value = toCopy.value;
    }   

    public MyObject(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject s1 = new MyObject(0);
        MyObject s2 = new MyObject(s1);
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);                       // false
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode()); // false
    }
}
```

It all depends on how the programmer of the class defines which objects to consider equal.

Comment: Nit: Java does not have *references*, Java has *pointers* (as a reference can not be null), hence the 'NullPointerException' :-)

Comment: Like it or not, but in Java they are called *references* (even though the standard is not consistent about it, like in your "Null*Pointer*Exception").

Comment: ...and even though their "references" might not comply with everyone's definitions of the term "reference". They probably chose the term to make it clear that there is no pointer arithmetics in Java - but that's just my guess.